# How to control depth of stacktrace

Tags: c#, wpf, stack-trace

Have C# WPF application using DevExpress. Catching an unhandled exception, see below, which shows System and DevExpress elements but nothing from any of my source modules. Almost certainly, one of my source modules is writing into a C# object that is bound to a DevExpress PropertyGridControl that is then throwing the exception, but which PropertyGridControl? Is there a way to expand or enlarge the stack trace depth, to see where in my source the write to the C# object is occurring?

```
OnDispatcherUnhandledException occurred: Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated. 
at System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary.NodeKeyValueCollection.NodeKeyValueEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__94`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
at DevExpress.Mvvm.Native.LinqExtensions.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action)
at DevExpress.Xpf.PropertyGrid.Internal.DataController.InvalidateChildren(IEnumerable`1 handles)
at DevExpress.Xpf.PropertyGrid.Internal.DataController.UpdateHandles()
at DevExpress.Xpf.PropertyGrid.Internal.DataController.Update()
at DevExpress.Xpf.PropertyGrid.Internal.DataViewBase.<Update>b__98_0()
at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Locker.DoLockedAction(Action action)
at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Locker.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<DoLockedActionIfNotLocked>b__0()
at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Locker.DoIfNotLocked(Action action)
at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Locker.DoLockedActionIfNotLocked(Action action)
at DevExpress.Xpf.PropertyGrid.Internal.DataViewBase.Update()
at DevExpress.Xpf.PropertyGrid.PropertyGridControl.UpdateData()
at DevExpress.Xpf.PropertyGrid.PropertyGridView.<OnLayoutUpdated>b__103_0(PropertyGridControl x)
at DevExpress.Mvvm.Native.MayBe.Do[TI](TI input, Action`1 action)
at DevExpress.Xpf.PropertyGrid.PropertyGridView.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Comment: Well, but your code writing something into an object might not have something to do with the call **stack** that leads to the exception. For all i know, your code might write something to the object, then return back to the caller, and then the caller calls something else that leads to the error (the call of your code returning makes it not being part of the call stack anymore). Or, perhaps your code writes to the object in some other thread, whereas the UI thread executes the methods seen in your call stack that leads to a method being called that stumbles over the data in the object...

Comment: The error you get: "_Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated._" is pretty telling. While the UI(?) thread is in the midst of enumerating over the/a collection, some other thread or a callback (through a delegate/lambda expression) modifies that collection. Look at the stacktrace to identify the involved UI component(s), from there figure out which collection(s) is/are related to those UI component(s), and from there figure out where and what exactly your code is doing with this collection precisely when (in respect to control-flow of your program).

Comment: I confess to not knowing for certain the internals of data binding, but intuitively I write to my object, which is bound to a DevExpress PropertyGridControl object, and C# not only updates my object but then calls into DevExpress to let it update its object, which ultimately hits the UI, some cell on some screen. You appear to be suggesting there is a disconnect between my write and DevExpress updating its bound object, so that the stack trace doesn't see my write, which effectively was the instigator of the exception. Is that possible? DevExpress wants to see my PropertyGridControl XAML.

Comment: "_Is that possible?_" Yes, of course it is possible. Technically the call stack (of some thread) "**saw**" the call to the method where you modified the object. But the call stack is called a "stack" (and not a "call log") for a reason. In case you don't know/aren't sure what the nature and/or purpose of a call stack is in a program, google for the term. There are plenty of articles and posts in the interwebs that explain in various ways what a call stack is (and because it's the interwebs, some of those articles, especially from low-quality sources/web sites, are sure to be wrong... ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

To their credit, DevExpress has owned up to an implementation that causes the exception I am observing. Their code processes DataContext binding asynchronously, so apparently while one binding update is being asynchronously processed, another binding update occurring concurrently can result in kaboom. New release soon...